# how can i get this graph by python?

Tags: python, matlab, graph, octave

i have written this code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig=plt.figure()

r=np.arange(1,2)
theta=np.linspace(0,np.pi/2)

x=r*np.cos(theta)
y=r*np.sin(theta)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

and get this graph.
[image: pyplot output]

but i want to get the graph below.

[image: desired output]

i'm confused about how to set a proper range of `r`.
i want to set `r`'s range `1<=r<=2`, but don't know how to do that.
how can i modify my code?

Comment: Why are `matlab` and `octave` tagged here?

Comment: Is `P == R` and `Q == S`?

Comment: have a look at https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
theta = np.linspace(0,np.pi/2)

for i in range(1,3):
    x = []
    y = []
    for t in theta:
       if t == 0:
          y.append(0)
          x.append(3-1)
       elif t == np.pi/2:
          y.append(3-1)
          x.append(0)
       else:
          x.append(i*np.cos(t))
          y.append(i*np.sin(t)) 
   plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is the second `if` supposed to be `elif`?